# Proof Strategies for Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to understand how to choose epsilons during proofs for convergent sequences. It seems that many proofs just state the epsilon to choose without any motivation? How should I go about in doing this?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but usually $\varepsilon$ is left general while the key to the proof is finding $N$ such that $n\geq  N$ implies $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do you mean choosing $\delta$? $\varepsilon$ must be left arbitrary; you cannot choose it.

Comment: I mean finding the N

Comment: I just started learning it, and it seems like there is no motivation when they choose N in the proof in that it seems like you have to find through trial and error sometimes

Comment: @user168530 do you have an example in mind? Usually the sequence will be given in a way that allows you to find $N$

Answer (score 1):

The method of proof is usually in the opposite order to the order of discovery. The ancient Greeks called this "analysis". Then when they found how to do a proof, they went through the steps backwards and got a rigorous proof!

Anyway, getting to specifics, a systematic way to do this is to determine $\tilde N(\epsilon)=\sup\{i\in\mathbb{Z};\,\vert x_i-b\vert\ge\epsilon\}$. Then let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N=\tilde N(\epsilon)+1$. And magically you get $\vert x_i-b\vert<\epsilon$ for all $i\ge N$.